# How do i remove a particular number of an array of various strings?

Tags: javascript

Suppose if I have data like the following array

```
"groupMapData": [
        {
            "menu_id": 17,
            "menu_name_message_id": "menuName.viewgroups",
            "access_role_ids": "3,1,4"
        },
        {
            "menu_id": 18,
            "menu_name_message_id": "menuName.creategroup",
            "access_role_ids": "2,1,4,3"
        }
    ]


checkboxfunction = (menuName, role, menuname) => {
        return menuname.some(menu => {
            let nameMatches = menu['menu_name_message_id'] === menuName,
                roleIncluded = menu['access_role_ids'].split(',')
                    .map(n => parseInt(n, 10))
                    .includes(role)
            return nameMatches && roleIncluded
        })
    }

findIndexfunction = (menuname,data) => {
    return data.findIndex(i => {
        return i.menu_name_message_id == menuname
    })
}


handleChange = (menuname, role, data) => event => {
    debugger
    let old_index_value=this.findIndexfunction(menuname, data)
    let old_roles=data[old_index_value].access_role_ids

    if (old_index_value) {
        if(event.target.checked){
            old_roles=old_roles.concat(role)
        }else{
            old_roles=old_roles.splice(old_index_value,1)  
        }
    }else{
        this.setState({ data: data })
    }

}




checked={groupMapData.length ? this.checkboxfunction("menuName.viewgroups", 2, groupMapData) : false}


 onChange={this.handleChange('menuName.viewgroups', 2, groupMapData)}
```

I am sending data,role, menuname from handlechange, now i want to change checkbox value based on the accessrole.

if its there in the accessrole, it has to be checked else unchecked.

Comment: On what condition you want to remove?

Comment: Okay I want to change the status of checkbox actually 

<Checkbox
                                         checked={groupMapData.length ? this.checkboxfunction("menuName.creategroup", 2, groupMapData) : false}
                                                    onChange={this.handleChange('menuName.creategroup', 2, groupMapData)}
                                                    //value= "General Admin can create new group"
                                                    color="primary"

                                                />

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: added in question

Answer (score 0):

Ohk let's use map

```
access_role_details.map((x)=>{
let role = x.access_role_ids
let roleArray = role.split(',');

//now we filter to remove the number you don't like eg. 4

roleArray.filter(k=>k != 4)

//now convert the array to a string and put it back

x.access_role_ids = roleArray.toString();

//return x now

return x;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {"access_role_details": [
      {
          "menu_id": 17,
          "menu_name_message_id": "menuName.viewgroups",
          "access_role_ids": "3,1,4"
      },
      {
          "menu_id": 18,
          "menu_name_message_id": "menuName.creategroup",
          "access_role_ids": "2,1,4,3"
      }
  ]
          };

var objData = obj.access_role_details[0];
var removeItem = "1";

var tempArr = objData.access_role_ids.split(","); // convert comma separated to array

var index = tempArr.indexOf(removeItem);
if(index !=-1){
  tempArr.splice(index,1);
}
objData.access_role_ids = tempArr.join(); // convert array to comma separated value

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert string to array and remove the specific element and again join the array to string.

We can achieve this using string operation but a better way is to convert it into the array and then perform the deletion operation. It will give the correct result to you.

refer following code :

```
var myObj = JSON.parse(`{"access_role_details": [
              {
                  "menu_id": 17,
                  "menu_name_message_id": "menuName.viewgroups",
                  "access_role_ids": "3,1,4"
              },
              {
                  "menu_id": 18,
                  "menu_name_message_id": "menuName.creategroup",
                  "access_role_ids": "2,1,4,3"
              }
          ]}`);


        var tempArr = [];
        var ResultArr = [];
        var access_role_id = 1;//Value you want to remove from the access_role_ids 
        for (var i = 0; i < myObj.access_role_details.length; i++)
        {
             tempArr = [];
             ResultArr = [];
             // split method to covert into array
             tempArr = myObj.access_role_details[i].access_role_ids.split(',');
             ResultArr = tempArr.filter(item => item != access_role_id);
             //join method to convert it into string with ',' seprated
             myObj.access_role_details[i].access_role_ids = ResultArr.join(',');
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj))
```

Comment: can i know what is this ?              ResultArr = tempArr.filter(item => item != access_role_id);

Comment: tempArr is containing the array of access_role_ids. I am applying the filter  operation on array of access_role_ids to remove the particular access_role_id from the access_role_ids  array. filter method will return the array with removed particular access_role_id.

Comment: there is something wrong with this syntax item => item != access_role_id

Comment: Filter method will return the all array element expect access_role_id. access_role_id will be the id which you want to remove from the access_role_ids.